# Sitecore - how to preview an unpublishable item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a simple requirement to be able to setup and preview pages in advance. The pages are for publication on a particular day and are one-off publications. They must not be visible prior to publication.

How can I preview the item prior to publication without making anything public?

If I restrict **the version** (i.e. version 1) from being published, I still get a published page showing standard values i.e. version 0 of the item.

If I restrict **the item** from being published, I can no longer preview it. It seems that the preview function has a dependancy on the item being publishable.

Am I missing a trick here?

**Update** : I'm particularly interested in why I can't preview the item when the item is restricted, as this is possibly the most intuitive restriction a user can use.

Comment: The root of why you can't preview an unpublishable item lies in what exactly preview is doing. Basically, it's showing you a version of the website and it's following all the rules that would show you what the website would look like. In order to give an accurate representation of the site, it needs to follow all the rules.  Say someone wanted to confirm that it wouldn't show, then they'd expect to not be able to preview it.

Comment: Thank you! Good point, this explains it. I had been looking at the preview function as previewing content by looking at the master database. As 'publishing' isn't required to do that, I didn't see why it affected preview. 

While I now understand the behaviour, it seems pretty unhelpful. I'd expect more people would like to preview content without the risk of it being published - marked unpublishable, than those wanting to 'preview' the fact that that it is indeed unpublishable. I could think of numerous ways of indicating this to the user while still allowing preview, but that another story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a date restriction on the version or the item.

Then go to the preview mode and use the date selector to select a different date.

[image]

When you select a date that falls within the publication date range, your item will be visible in the preview.

**Update:**
As you're particularly interested in previewing restricted items; it can be done if you setup a new site and point it to the `master` database instead of the usual `web` database.

This is explained in [a blogpost by Mark Ursino](http://firebreaksice.com/how-to-setup-a-sitecore-preview-site-to-review-content-before-publishing/).

Answer (score 3):

As Rudd mentioned, [my blog post](http://firebreaksice.com/how-to-setup-a-sitecore-preview-site-to-review-content-before-publishing/) explains how to do this. However, you can also setup a new workflow provider by Alex Shyba that allows for semi-final workflow states and thus allows publishing to them: [Publish to pre-production web database. Part 2.](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/09/publish-to-pre-production-web-database.html)